# JSON need nested array for JavaScriptSerializer without naming the element

Tags: c#, json, json.net, javascriptserializer

I would like to use JavaScriptSerializer for this because I'm afraid of how many things might break and I can't change anything on the client-side.

If Json.Net is the best way to go then I will try it but I need an example.

I have this class

**Class Definition**

```
[DataContract] 
[Serializable] 
public class Family 
{
    [DataMember(Order = 0)]
    public List<Member> members { get; set; }
}

[DataContract] 
[Serializable] 
public class Member 
{
    [DataMember(Order = 0)]    
    public string FName { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string LName { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public string DOB { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 4)]
    public string Type { get; set; } 
}
```

The JSON I am Deserializing looks like this

**JSON Example**

```
[
    {
        "Family": [
            {
                "FName": "Jane",
                "LName": "Prospect",
                "DOB": "04/01/1980",    
                "Gender": "Female",
                "Type": "Adult"
            },
            {...}
        ]
    },
    { 
        "OptionChoice": 34,
        "OptionText": "Aquatics"
    },
    {...},
    {...}
]
```

I can deserialize the Answer objects fine (OptionChoice,OptionText).
Hower the answer object has an additional item full of nulls where it is parsing the Family section of the JSON. I don't really want that.

When I try to deserialize the Family part I get an error

```
Type 'Family' is not supported for deserialization of an array.
```

It says it has a null for the Family.members. Is it looking for "Family": [ "members": {...},{...}] ?

How can I get this working without changing the JSON example?

---

### Update After dbc Answer:

Here is my model

```
[DataContract]
[Serializable]
public class Answer
{
    [DataMember(Order = 2, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public int FormID { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 3,EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public int Question { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 5)]
    public int OptionChoice { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 6,IsRequired = false)]
    public string OptionText { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 5, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public bool lockAnswer { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 1,EmitDefaultValue= false)]
    public List<FamilyMember> Family { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
[Serializable]
public class FamilyMember
{
    [DataMember(Order = 0)]
    public string FName { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string LName { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public string DOB { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 4)]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

At this point in my creation of my SO update I solved the problem with [Rubber Duck Debugging](http://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/)

Turns out I had some regex that was stripping all "[" & "]" then manually adding them back but only on the ends.

This cool comparison tool at http://pro.jsonlint.com/ helped btw.

Thanks! If anybody in the future reads this and wants to show a testable way to do this in JSON.net (I tried but got stuck) please do.

Comment: Clarified. Thanks for suggesting that.

Comment: Is this your real JSON?  It looks like your outer container is an array containing objects with no common propertyes.  Is that correct?  Of has the example been oversimplified?

Comment: It is not oversimplified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question includes two related questions:

1. Exception loading the `Family` list.

   The problem here is that, as you suspect, there is no property corresponding to `members`.  What your JSON has is an array of objects, each of which might have an array-valued property `Family`.  Thus your data model should look like:

   ```
   public class ResponseItem
   {
       public int? OptionChoice { get; set; }
       public string OptionText { get; set; }
       public List<FamilyMember> Family { get; set; }
       // Other fields not shown from {...}
   }

   public class FamilyMember
   {
       public string FName { get; set; }
       public string LName { get; set; }
       public string DOB { get; set; }
       public string Gender { get; set; }
       public string Type { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. You state, "Hower the answer object has an additional item full of nulls where it is parsing the Family section of the JSON. I don't really want that."  This could be done by deserializing the JSON into a polymorphic array where each possible derived type has just the minimal number of fields.  However, since there is no [`__type` information](http://blog.shrichards.com/til-why-type-is-added-when-i-serialize-to-json/) in your JSON, you will need to add some slightly fussy logic to chose the correct concrete type for each array element.  Your data model would look like:

   ```
   public interface IResponseItem // base interface for all possible responses
   {
   }

   public class FamilyResponse : IResponseItem
   {
       public List<FamilyMember> Family { get; set; }
   }

   public class OptionsResponse : IResponseItem
   {
       public int OptionChoice { get; set; }
       public string OptionText { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   In complex serialization situations like this people seem to prefer Json.NET, nevertheless it's still possible with `JavaScriptSerializer` as per your question.  You must code up a [`JavaScriptConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to select the appropriate derived type from the base `IResponseItem` type by matching the property names, for instance:

   ```
   public class PolymorphicTypeConverter : JavaScriptConverter
   {
       public Type BaseType { get; private set; }

       public Type[] DerivedTypes { get; private set; }

       public PolymorphicTypeConverter(Type baseType, IEnumerable<Type> derivedTypes)
       {
           this.BaseType = baseType;
           this.DerivedTypes = derivedTypes.ToArray();
       }

       static MemberInfo FindMember(Type type, string name)
       {
           try
           {
               var propInfo = type.GetProperty(name,
                   BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public);
               if (propInfo != null
                   && propInfo.GetSetMethod() != null
                   && propInfo.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0)
                   return propInfo;
               var fieldInfo = type.GetField(name,
                   BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public);
               if (fieldInfo != null)
                   return fieldInfo;
           }
           catch (AmbiguousMatchException)
           {
               return null;
           }
           return null;
       }

       IEnumerable<Type> AncestorsAndSelf(Type type)
       {
           for (; type != null; type = type.BaseType)
               if (DerivedTypes.Contains(type))
                   yield return type;
       }

       Type FindUniqueTypeMatch(IDictionary<string, object> jsonProperties)
       {
           List<Type> matches = new List<Type>();

           foreach (var type in DerivedTypes)
           {
               if (type.IsInterface)
                   continue; // Bug?
               bool isMatch = true;
               foreach (var name in jsonProperties.Keys)
               {
                   if (FindMember(type, name) == null)
                   {
                       isMatch = false;
                       break;
                   }
               }
               if (isMatch)
               {
                   matches.Add(type);
               }
           }
           if (matches.Count == 0)
               return null;
           else if (matches.Count == 1)
               return matches[0];
           else
           {
               // Multiple matches.
               // If there is a common base type to all matches, return it.  Otherwise, give up.
               var candidates = AncestorsAndSelf(matches[0]).Reverse();
               foreach (var match in matches.Skip(1))
               {
                   candidates = candidates.Zip(AncestorsAndSelf(match).Reverse(), (t1, t2) => (t1 == t2 ? t1 : null)).Where(t => t != null);
               }
               return candidates.LastOrDefault();
           }
       }

       public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
       {
           var subtype = FindUniqueTypeMatch(dictionary);
           if (subtype == null)
               throw new JsonSerializationException();
           var method = serializer.GetType().GetMethod("ConvertToType");
           var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(subtype);
           return generic.Invoke(serializer, new object [] { dictionary } );
       }

       public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
       {
           // Should never be called.
           throw new NotImplementedException();
       }

       public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
       {
           get
           {
               return new Type[] { BaseType };
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   This only works when each object in your JSON array has properties that match one and only one type in the derived type array.  If this cannot be guaranteed, because, for instance, null fields were not serialized leading to multiple matches, you will need to enhance the converter to make a best guess match.

   Then call it like:

   ```
       var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
       serializer.RegisterConverters(new JavaScriptConverter[] { new PolymorphicTypeConverter(typeof(IResponseItem), new Type[] { typeof(FamilyResponse), typeof(OptionsResponse) }) });
       var responseArray = serializer.Deserialize<IResponseItem[]>(json);
   ```

Comment: I am having trouble with Part 1 of your answer. I will update my question